# C. Problem reading in the pixels of a BMP image

Tags: c, image, pixel

I am trying to read in the pixels of a BMP image with the code below. First I read in the relevant image data (width, height and header) using my function "readBMPHeader". Next I want to read in the pixels of the file line by line using the function "mapBMP". However, the values I get for the pixels of the bmp image "dali", which you can find below, are not correct and I do not know what I am doing wrong. Could you please tell me where my fault is?[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//Macros
#define ALIGNMENT 4
#define HEADER_LOCATION 0x0000
#define DATA_START_LOCATION 0x000A
#define WIDTH_LOCATION 0x0012
#define HEIGHT_LOCATION 0x0016
#define BITS_PER_PIXEL_LOCATION 0x001C


typedef unsigned char byte;



int readBMPHeader(unsigned int* image_header, unsigned int* image_height, unsigned int* image_width,
                  unsigned int* image_start, const char* file_name)
{
  // Here we open the given file for reading in binary mode.
  FILE* image = fopen(file_name, "rb");

  // Here we check whether opening the given file was successful.
  if (image == NULL)
  {
    printf("Invalid File\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Here we read in the header of the given BM image.
  fseek(image, HEADER_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
  fread(image_header, 2, 1, image);
  // Here we read in the height of the given BM image.
  fseek(image, HEIGHT_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
  fread(image_height, 4, 1, image);
  // Here we read in the width of the given BM image.
  fseek(image, WIDTH_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
  fread(image_width, 4, 1, image);
  fseek(image, DATA_START_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
  fread(image_start, 4, 1, image);
  fclose(image);

  return 0;

}

void mapBMP(unsigned int height, unsigned int width, char mapped_image[height][width], unsigned int image_start, const char* file_name)
{
  FILE* image = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  // Here we read in the number of bits per pixel in the given BM image.
  unsigned int bits_per_pixel;
  fseek(image, BITS_PER_PIXEL_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
  fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);
  // Here we compute the number of bytes per pixel in the given BM image.
  unsigned int bytes_per_pixel = ((unsigned int) bits_per_pixel) / 8;
  printf("Bytes per pixel = %u \n", bytes_per_pixel);
  // Here we compute the stride, i.e. the number of bytes in a row (rounded up by alignment)
  unsigned int stride = (width * bytes_per_pixel) + (ALIGNMENT - 1);
  stride /= ALIGNMENT;
  stride *= ALIGNMENT;
  // Here we read in the pixels of the image, the loops have been shortened for testing purposes.
  byte pixel[bytes_per_pixel];
  for (unsigned int i = height - 1; i > height - 2; i = i - 1) // The proper condition is:(unsigned int i = height - 1; i > 0; i = i - 1)
  {
    fseek(image, i * stride, image_start);

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 30; j = j + 1) // The proper condition is: (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
    {
      fread(pixel, 3, 1, image);
      printf("pixel = %x %x %x\n", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]);
    }
  }

  fclose(image);
}

int main()
{


  // Here is the BMP Image test.
  unsigned int image_header;
  unsigned int image_width;
  unsigned int image_height;
  unsigned int image_start;
  char* file_name = "dali.bmp";
  int file_opened = readBMPHeader(&image_header, &image_height, &image_width, &image_start, file_name);

  if (file_opened == -1)
    printf("File could not be opened.");
  else
  {
    // Some prints to see the collected data.
    printf("Size of byte in byte = %llu \n", sizeof(byte));
    printf("header (in hex) = %x \n", image_header);
    printf("height (in pixels) = %u \n", image_height);
    printf("width (in pixels) = %u \n", image_width);
    printf("image_start (in bytes) = %u \n", image_start);

    char mapped_image[image_height][image_width];
    mapBMP(image_height, image_width, mapped_image, image_start, file_name);
    //printTable(image_height, image_width, mapped_image);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Here is how the file looks in my Hex Editor; I highlighted the offset of the image data.

[image]

Here is my output, it appears that I am still in the header part of the BMP instead of the image start, which I do not understand.

[image]

And here is how the file is stored in my folder, I do not think that it is compressed as it has 1133 KB size.

[image]

Comment: The code seems to be a bit of a hotch-potch. You have `char mapped_image[image_height][image_width];` which doesn't take account of `bytes_per_pixel` and then this array is ignored.

Comment: You have `unsigned int image_header;` but only read 2 bytes into it.

Comment: You're also ignoring the return values from almost every function you call.

Comment: You did the same thing with `unsigned int bits_per_pixel; ... fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);`

Comment: `fseek(image, i * stride, SEEK_SET);` is not correct because the image data doesn't start at the beginning of the file. There is information in the headers that tell you where the image data starts.

Comment: @user3386109: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected my code, but I still get the wrong pixels.

Comment: You should also perhaps check the compression field of the header to see if the bitmap data is compressed.

Comment: @3nondatur "I corrected my code" lacks info.  What code did you use?  "I corrected my code," lacks info too.  Provide some samples of output expected and output seen.

Comment: @3nondatur Post your output from "Size of byte" up to the first few pixels.

Comment: If you are on Windows, this is incredibly easy with GDI+.

Comment: @3nondatur Is your updated code still using `unsigned int bits_per_pixel; ...
  fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);` and not the correct `unsigned short bits_per_pixel;
...   fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);`?  Corrected per [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292809/c-problem-reading-in-the-pixels-of-a-bmp-image/76293147?noredirect=1#comment134536894_76292809) too?

Comment: From the hex dump, the file is a BMP file, image size 754x512, 24 bits per pixel, not compressed. The bitmap info header is 124 bytes, which means that it's a BITMAPV5HEADER [according to this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#DIB_header_(bitmap_information_header)). I've only used the 40 byte header, so it's up to OP to figure out what the other 84 bytes mean. But in any case, the two headers have a total of 138 bytes, so the bitmap data starts at offset 138 in the file.

Comment: The image width is 754 pixels, and there are 3 bytes per pixels. Since `754*3` is not a multiple of 4, two bytes of padding are added at the end of each line. Therefore, the number of bytes per line is 2264. Total bytes for the image is `2264*512 = 1159168` which agrees with the value in the info header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On review, posted picture is a .png file size with 675K bytes.
This may be an artifact of OP uploading the picture.

Will review OP's issue with recently added info.

---

At least these issues:

**Incorrect use of `fseek()`**

```
// fseek(image, i * stride, image_start);
fseek(image, i * stride + image_start, SEEK_SET);
```

**Incorrect read width**

```
// int readBMPHeader(unsigned int* image_header, ...
// ...
// fread(image_header, 2, 1, image);

int readBMPHeader(uint16_t* image_header, ...
...
fread(image_header, sizeof *image_header, 1, image);
```

and

```
// unsigned int bits_per_pixel;
// ...
// fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);

uint16_t bits_per_pixel;
...
fread(&bits_per_pixel, sizeof bits_per_pixel, 1, image);
```

Tip: avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

---

Better code would test and report all the hex data of the header to insure expected encoding.

Better to use fixed width `uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t` types than `char, unsigned` for reading the file.

Ref [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not think that the file is compressed, see my edit above.